# CMake SDL and add_subdirectory

Tags: cmake, directx, sdl

I'm trying to add SDL library to list of my third parties. For this, I create CMakeLists.txt file which contains:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.1.3)
project(TestProject)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(test_project index.cpp)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES (3dparty/sdl/include)

ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(3dparty/sdl EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(test_project general SDL2)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(test_project general SDL2main)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(test_project debug SDL2)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(test_project debug SDL2main)
```

When I generate VS13 project, the libs, which SLD link for their targets() occurs in target "test_project". 
List of linked libs in test_project target:

```
kernel32.lib
user32.lib
gdi32.lib
winspool.lib
shell32.lib
ole32.lib
oleaut32.lib
uuid.lib
comdlg32.lib
advapi32.lib
3dparty\sdl\Debug\SDL2main.lib
3dparty\sdl\Debug\SDL2.lib
winmm.lib
imm32.lib
version.lib
dinput8.lib
dxguid.lib
dxerr.lib
```

But should be like this:

```
3dparty\sdl\Debug\SDL2main.lib
3dparty\sdl\Debug\SDL2.lib
```

In target "test_project" I dont include path to DirectX SDK libs. Therefore the linker tells me:

```
 LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'dxerr.lib'
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a feature. [CMake transitively passes on public link dependencies.](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/target_link_libraries.html)

That is, if SDL has a public link dependency to `dxerr.lib`, so will have any executables that link to SDL.

I see two possibilities now: Either SDL has a bug in their build scripts and incorrectly declares a library as a public dependency when it should be private. Or there is indeed a legitimate dependency which needs to be resolved by your executable.

The latter would for instance be true in case you are building SDL as a static library and not a DLL. Remember that static libraries do not pass through the linker, which means all dependencies of the static lib get passed on to the executable or DLL that links them.

Comment: So, when I delete the dependencies in main project, it works fine.

Comment: Thanks, I just put "LINK_PRIVATE" in CMakeLists.txt file in SDL sources, and it works now.

Comment: @YaroslavMytsyo You might want to [file a bug](https://bugzilla.libsdl.org/) with SDL in this case (If nothing else this will verify that your workaround is correct).

Answer (score 0):

After ComicSansMS's advance, I put "LINK_PRIVATE" in target_link_libraries in CMakeLists.txt file in SDL sources, and it works now.